# Swift, polar coordinates

Tags: swift, geometry, polar-coordinates

I have to draw 12 points in a circle with different radiant. From point 1, draw a line to point 2, from point 2 to 3, etc. The lines will not be a problem.

I can not find a formula to find the 12 * (x,y), but I think it's something with polar coordinates / circle?

Is anyone working with it and maybe want to share with me?

See the picture which might explain better than I can:

[image: Circle]

Comment: Hi allan can you please add the picture. :)

Comment: Thanks, can you see the picture now?

Comment: You need to read maths about that to place your points using Polar System to (x,y) one more classic. Drawing a line once you get your two points, that's easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the result I got:

[image]

And This is my Playground:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Foundation
import UIKit

class DemoView: UIView {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let origin = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2, y: frame.size.height / 2)
        let radius = frame.size.width / 2

        self.createCircle(origin: origin, radius: radius)
        self.addLinesInCircle(origin: origin, radius: radius)
    }

    func createCircle(origin: CGPoint, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.addArc(withCenter: origin, radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(2 * Double.pi), clockwise: true)
        path.close()
        UIColor.orange.setFill()
        path.fill()
    }

    func addLinesInCircle(origin: CGPoint, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        let incrementAngle: CGFloat = CGFloat.pi / 6
        let ratios: [CGFloat] = [3/6, 5/6, 3/6, 1/6, 5/6, 2/6, 4/6, 2/6, 4/6, 4/6, 4/6, 4/6, 3/6]

        for (index, ratio) in ratios.enumerated() {
            let point = CGPoint(x: origin.x + cos(CGFloat(index) * incrementAngle) * radius * ratio,
                                y: origin.y + sin(CGFloat(index) * incrementAngle) * radius * ratio)
            if index == 0 {
                path.move(to: point)
            } else {
                path.addLine(to: point)
            }
        }
        path.close()
        UIColor.black.set()
        path.stroke()
    }

}

let demoView = DemoView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 320))
```

Comment: THANKS, that is what I need :-)

Comment: How to add smooth curves/spline curves ? Thanks!

Comment: @Toldy, I was trying to create a textLayer but inside the circle at the 5/6th of the radius. but I want it to be inside the arc and not on the line, I want to get the point inside the arc